# Remove CNAME after Azure has verified the domain

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, cname

Once I have verified my domain in Azure with the CNAME record, can I remove the CNAME record safely from my DNS server without breaking anything?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: I would say Azure is used by developers more than sys admins, but posted on server fault. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely delete the **awverify** records. Those are used only when validating the custom domain (while associating a new domain in the portal) and post that, they are not used so feel free to remove them.

Comment: How do you know this?  Is there any supporting documentation to confirm?